# Navigating UI with dpad prevents navigation with thumbstick in Unity new input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a custom `InputActionAsset`, but I have setup a UI action map that is based on the `DefaultInputActions`.

I configured a binding for the LeftStick with a press interaction. I did this to make the stick work more like a button press while navigating UI elements. Otherwise, any events attached to navigation fire off multiple times per press of the thumbstick. It looks like this:

[image: LeftStick Binding Config]

D-Pad is configured with no interactions, and Navigate is setup as Passthrough / Vector2.

The problem I've encountered is that the LeftStick works absolutely fine to navigate the UI, unless I happen to use the D-Pad. If I use the D-pad to navigate the UI, the LeftStick becomes completely unresponsive. The event attached to `GameInput.UI.Navigate.performed` will not fire, and no selections are changed. The LeftStick will not become useable again unless I change Windows focus to another application, and back again.

I tried using a composite for the LeftStick, it operates the same as my current config.

This problem does not occur if I use the keyboard for navigation, and then choose to use the LeftStick.

The problem occurs in both Unity and build.

If I remove the press interaction from the LeftStick, this problem does not occur. In this case, the issue is that `GameInput.UI.Navigate.performed` will fire 50+ times for each selection change.

I don't understand why this is happening, and it feels like maybe it's a bug. The docs on all this are sort of convoluted, so it makes it difficult to understand intended behavior. I'm not attempting to use both the stick and the pad at the exact same time, but one press of the D-Pad renders LeftStick unusable.

I'm open to other suggestions that will allow the LeftStick, D-Pad, or Keyboard keys to navigate the UI without calling the `performed` event countless times.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to file a bug report to Unity, it has a good change to be addressed, and you may also want to duplicate it on forums in the Input System section (mentioning the report is filed). For me it seems like another bug of the Input System. Hope they'll react and fix.

Comment: @xander thank you, I went ahead and made a bug post on their forum with this information to see what comes of it. If someone posts an alternate solution, or confirmation that this is a bug, I will post back here.